# Is it possible to analyse the effect of both factors and numeric variables at the same time in a limma model?

Tags: r, limma

I try to perfom an analysis of gene expression data with the limma r package. My model includes factors and numerical covariates and I'm not able to get the results for both types of variables at once.

Here is an example:

```
design <- model.matrix(~0+Factor+NumericCov,data=sampleData)
fit <- lmFit(geneExprData,design)
cont.matrix <- makeContrasts(Factor1=FactorLevel2-FactorLevel1,
                             Factor2=FactorLevel3-FactorLevel2,
                             Factor2=FactorLevel1-FactorLevel3,
                             NumericCov = NumericCov,
                             levels=design)
fit <- contrasts.fit(fit, cont.matrix)
fit <- eBayes(fit)
topTable(fit,coef="Factor1")
topTable(fit,coef="Factor2")
topTable(fit,coef="Factor3")
topTable(fit,coef="NumericCov")
```

Is this correct? Or should I just not use a contrast matrix for the analysis of the effect of numeric covariates?
If I do not use the `makeContrast` function it is more difficult to look at the difference between all the levels of the factor (which I need to do).
So if this is not correct, is there nevertheless a way to define the constrasts in order do both parts of the analysis at once?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are asking a specific programming question but a question about a proper analysis strategy. Such questions aren't really on-topic on Stack Overflow. If you need statistical consulting you should ask over at [stats.se] or since it's a gene expression question, maybe https://www.biostars.org/ would be a good choice.

Comment: @MrFlick this question is about the use of the limma package in r rather than about an analysis strategy, but you are right, biostars.org might be an option